# Tengo un Inconveniente de conexión MySQL con proyecto Java Web en IntelliJ

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, maven, conexión

**El tema es asi, la idea de esto es crear un sistema de login y register, entonces en estos archivos, hago la conexion mysql, pero parece que hay un error o algo, yo al menos pienso que es eso. Aclaro que recien estoy empezando en lo que es Java.**

**El error que me da es el siguiente, y solo sucede cuando apreto el boton registrar:**

Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error
Tipo Informe de Excepción

mensaje Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.close()" because "con" is null

Descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.close()" because "con" is null
com.cac.conferencia.controllers.RegisterController.doPost(RegisterController.java:57)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de registro del servidor.

Apache Tomcat/10.1.11

**Entonces, busque y busque y segun lo que lei puede ser que no me este agarrando el driver para conectar el MySQL, entonces recurri a ir al pom.xml, y agregar las dependencia, pero eso no funcionó.
Luego leí que tal vez instalando el archivo de forma manual lo solucionaria, y la verdad que tampoco funcionó.
Implemente un cambio al codigo que es:**

```
package com.cac.conferencia.controllers;

import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@WebServlet("/register")
public class RegisterController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String uname = request.getParameter("nombre");
        String usurname = request.getParameter("apellido");
        String uemail = request.getParameter("email");
        String upwd = request.getParameter("password");
        RequestDispatcher disp = null;
        Connection con = null;


        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usuarios?useSSL=false", "root", "1234");
            final String STATEMENT = "insert into users (nombre, apellido, email, password) values (?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(STATEMENT);
            pst.setString(1, uname);
            pst.setString(2, usurname);
            pst.setString(3, uemail);
            pst.setString(4, upwd);

            int rowCount = pst.executeUpdate();
            disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            if (rowCount > 0) {
                request.setAttribute("status", "success");
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("status", "failed");
            }

            disp.forward(request, response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Y bueno nada, eso seria mi duda completa y lo que intente hacer, asi que si alguien sabe sobre el tema, desde ya le estoy agradecido por leer y tomarse el tiempo de ver esta consulta.**